# Replace anything in certain position in string using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove empty all paragraph tags, regardless of what style attributes might be in the p tag, from a string. I want to remove, for example, all of these and replace with an empty string.

```
<p style="margin-left:0px"></p>
<p></p>
<p style="margin-left:1cm; margin-right:1cm"></p>
```

So far, to deal with one situation I have, I am doing this:

```
str = str.replace(/<p style=\"margin:0cm 0cm 10pt\"><\/p>/g,'')
```

which is working in that particular situation. How can I write it so it removes

```
<p AnythingHereInThisTag></p>
```

and replaces it with an empty string?

Edit - further to answer below - if I do this:

```
str = str.replace(/<p(.*)><\/p>/g,'')
```

it is replacing the whole string which might look like

```
<p>Hello</p><p>Some text in the middle</p><p>Goodbye</p>
```

It needs to look at each pair of

tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace Any charecter without a char `"` has the regex as `[^\"]`

```js
var reg=/\<p( [a-zA-Z]*=((\"[^\"]*\")|(\'[^\']*\')))*\>\<\/p\>/g;
console.log('<p style=\'margin:0cm 0cm 10pt\'></p>'.replace(reg,''));
console.log('<p style=\"margin:0cm 0cm 10pt\"></p>'.replace(reg,''));
console.log('<p style=\"margin:0cm 0cm 10pt\" class=\"test\"></p>'.replace(reg,''));
console.log('<p></p>'.replace(reg,''));
```

Comment: @Martin Smellworse check that now. it removes all empty paragraphs even with a class name or any new attribute

Comment: Thank you for that. It works ... but I still have a problem. Looking at the data I am trying to clean, I have data like this too ...
<p><span style="font-size:8pt"></span></p>
... so the <p> tag has some content - but no content that is not within tags. Any idea how I can get rid of those empty paragraphs too?

Comment: Actually, looking at the data again it is more complicated. It can be 
<p><span style="font-size:8pt"><span style="line-height:115%"></span></span></p>

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
str = 'asd<p style="margin-left:0px"></p><p></p><p style="margin-left:1cm; margin-right:1cm"></p>'
str.replace(/<p(.*)><\/p>/g,'') // "asd"
```

Reading the question again, it is unclear if you wanted to remove only the attributes within the

tag, or the tag completely. Please clarify.

You can read more about regular expression [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but I have a little problem. I am trying to remove all empty paragraphs from a long string that might contain, for example, 3 paragraphs. The string might look like <p>Hello</p><p>Good day</p><p>Goodbye</p>. The expression you posted removes everything between the first <p> and the last </p> i.e. it removes the whole string. How can I get it so it, as it were, looks at each pair of <p></p> tags and only removes ones with no content between the tags?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to remove the whole tag. If it is just <p></p> I need to remove it. If it is <p style="margin:0px"></p> I need to remove it.